# Update Array Value of same Key

Tags: javascript, html

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 40
  }
];
```

here you can see the nancy is occuring twice i want to add the age of two nancy and put in the array  that is

```
var family = [
  {
    name: "Mike",
    age: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Matt"
    age: 13
  },
  {
    name: "Nancy",
    age: 17
  },
  {
    name: "Adam",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Jenny",
    age: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Carl",
    age: 40
  }
];
```

means if the user enter the same detail twice then simply add the age and put it in the same place ..

Thank you!

Comment: what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.